Why does pectin/agar jelly taste sweet, if they stay solid at 36.5 °C, entrapping sugar?
When we eat pectin jelly(fruit jelly) or agar jelly, they taste sweet.
This should imply that sugar entrapped in gel network is somehow exposed and dissolved to saliva.
However, pectin and agar gel don't become liquid at 36.5 °C. Because pectin's ungel point is 50+ °C, and agar's ungel point is 85 °C. Then, how are we able to taste sugar inside these gels?

could just be diffusion of the sugar added to the jelly food. Without added sugars the pectin has no taste.

I assume that during quick licking of these jellies, the taste is not particularly sweet, but mixing it with saliva while chewing would speed up diffusion tremendously.

The word "gel" means that part of the material is liquid already (gas for aerogels) and the rest is nanostructured solid network. This liquid enables diffusion similar to that in ordinary liquids. Placing a piece of gel in a free liquid causes the concentration of sugar solution to equalize on both sides.
